# ngResource.myfunc().$promise.then returns empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource, ngresource

I'm using angularjs-1.5.0 to write my application.

I created a service that uses a $resource to fetch data from the api server. the service is called MyApi.

```
(function () {

angular.module('myalcoholist').factory('MyApi', ['$resource', '$auth', function ($resource, $auth) {
    return $resource('https://myalcoholist.com:8888/drink/:cmd',
        null, {
                 pouringSpeedTypes: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {api_token: $auth.getToken(), cmd: 'get_pouring_speed_types'},
                isArray: true
            },
            pouringLocationTypes: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {api_token: $auth.getToken(), cmd: 'get_pouring_location_types'},
                isArray: true
            }
        });
        });
}]);

})();
```

and in my controller i use this service using the following code:

```
 MyApi.pouringLocationTypes().$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.info(data);
    });
    MyApi.pouringSpeedTypes().$promise.then(function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    });
```

the problem is that the data is.. a promise i guess.
this is what data contains:

```
$promise: d
$resolved: true
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
```

what do I do with that? how do I get the actual data from the get request ?

Comment: maybe try `MyApi.pouringLocationTypes().then(function(data){ ... //do something with data })` this should give you whatever is returned from the API call for you to do whatever with

Comment: @HolyMoly I was just about to write that, but sometimes the way things are presented on here make you second guess if their way is now the `correct` way.

Comment: then is not defined when I try that

Comment: Your code looks correct. It is an issue with the Authorization or an issue with the server. Check your network tab to see what the server is returning.

Comment: What does `MyApi.pouringLocationTypes()` return then?

Comment: it looks like an empty array is being returned when i look at it in the browser

Comment: I get an empty array too https://myalcoholist.com:8888/drink/wine

Comment: https://myalcoholist.com/drink/get_pouring_location_types & https://myalcoholist.com/drink/get_pouring_speed_types both redirect back to the home page, but in the network tab i do see that I got a 200 for both urls, except nothing in the response object - so i think first you have to make sure you are getting something back, once you are - you can probably use the code exactly as you wrote it and do something with data

Comment: also, when i add the :8888 to the same urls i just typed above, i get `"code": "MethodNotAllowedError",
"message": "GET is not allowed" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your comments, you allowed me to pinpoint the issue.

first of all I didn't update my server's code that's why when you tried these addresses you got Method not Allowed.

the problem that i've been having is that these requests really returned empty arrays.

so first of all my API returns a json Object not an array so i changed isArray to false.

so after that and actually fixing my API Server, this is what I received:

```
$promise: d
$resolved: true
data: Array[4]
success: true
```

my API server returns a json with data and success. so things are working now! thanks a lot.